# Can't find element to make if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, if-statement, selenium-webdriver

Can't find certain element exists I would like to put into if statement: (EDIT)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sys
import smtplib

email = "CampbelltP5wRaX@hotmail.com"
pswd = "EiEHzciBT668"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actions = ActionChains(driver)


driver.get("http://www.tumblr.com/login")
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_email").send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_password").send_keys(pswd)
driver.find_element_by_id("signup_forms_submit").click()

#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

time.sleep(5)

iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
terminated = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'center_item')]/h1")



#terminated = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='account_actions_suspended']")



if terminated:
    driver.close()
```

after the login fails I would like for the page to determine if the account is suspended. The html is below:

[image]

I figured if I can find this element, I should be able to make an if statement.

This is my error:(EDIT)

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tumblrtest.py", line 32, in <module>
    terminated = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'center_item')]/h1")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 253, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 707, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 196, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.155)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Mac OS X 10.7.5 x86_64)`

Comment: you can use find_element_by_xpath. xpath you can get by inspect element in browser.

Comment: An `<h1>` tag is **NOT** an `<id>` tag!!!

Comment: I tried the xpath `//*[@id="account_actions_suspended"]` and it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var iframe = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
driver.switch().frame(iframe)
terminated = driver.find_element_by_Xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'center_item')]/h1")
```

Comment: @marriedjane875 I have updated my code your element is inside of iframe you have to switch to iframe first and then search for it.

Comment: it said `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tagName'`

Comment: nvm, its `..tag_name`

Comment: I get an err: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'switch'
`

Comment: maybe I should use the `driver.switch_to_frame()` method?

Comment: @marriedjane875 Yes , my code is c# code it was more to give you idea what to do , but if you translate it to Phyton it will work! It has to be driver.switch_to_frame() , because that is what you want.

Comment: @marriedjane875 No problem :)

Comment: I still get a `AttributeError: SwitchTo instance has no __call__ method
` err

Comment: maybe its a problem that the page isn't all the way loaded before it starts the code?..

Comment: @marriedjane875 The easiest way to check that is to debug your app, set the breakpoint to that line of code where you are searching for that element give it enough time before you press step forward.

Comment: yeah i put a `time.sleep(5)` to make sure, but it still gets an error around not being able to find the element. :\ ...I put the edited error up top.

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the `NoSuchElementException` to check that the element is exists or not. If it exists then the it's suspended.

Here is the example code in Java, as I'm not familiar in Python, but I think you'll understand it :)

```
try {
  WebElement terminated = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'center_item')]/h1"));
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  System.out.println("The user is not suspended");
}
```

If this error message appears in an iframe, or get loaded by ajax, then you should deal with these problems before my example code (switching to the iframe; explicit or implicit wait; etc...)